# Set values order based off other values logic

Tags: c#, logic

**How can I more efficiently check for null values and set their order accordingly?**

I have 3 fields (1, 2, 3) and I need to do a check to see if any of the string values are null and if so I need to move the respective value up to the next spot so if 2 is null but 3 is not I will need to move 3 into 2's spot.

My original thought was to do this with a series of if statements however after starting down that road I'm learning that my list of if statements is going to be substantial so I'm looking for a better way to preform this check and set my values.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(field1))
                {
                    fields.SetField("Field1", field1);
                    fields.SetField("Field2", field2);
                }
```

If I continued down the above route I would have to also preform a check for field 2 and 3 and etc... for each initial check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use this logic:

```
string firstNotNull = field1 ?? field2 ?? field3;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(field1)) fields.SetField("Field1", firstNotNull);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(field2)) fields.SetField("Field2", firstNotNull);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(field3)) fields.SetField("Field3", firstNotNull);
```

But the logic is not entirely clear. Do you also want to overwrite `Field3` with a value from `Field1` if the `Field3` is null and `Field1` not?

Maybe this generic approach is what you're looking for:

```
var stringColumns = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c => c.DataType == typeof(string)).ToList();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < stringColumns.Count; i++)
    {
        string field = row.Field<string>(i);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(field))
        {
            // check all after this:
            for (int ii = i + 1; ii < stringColumns.Count; ii++)
            {
                string nextField = row.Field<string>(ii);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextField))
                {
                    row.SetField(i, nextField);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Field1 should always have a value however Field2 and Field3 may not in which case they need to be moved as high as possible (respectively).

Comment: What means "they need to be moved as high as possible"?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said they need to go to the "top" or to Field1 or Field2.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the approach that i've just added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

If 'fields' is an IEnumerable collection of strings, you could simply call the Orderby() / OrderByDescending() method on it.

```
var sortedFields = fields.OrderBy(s => s);
// OR
var sortedFields = fields.OrderByDescending(s => s)
```